# Plotly: Add line to bar chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a plotly bar chart, from a dataframe:

```
fig = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='bar', barmode = 'relative')
py.iplot(fig)
```

Is it possible to turn one of the columns in the data frame into a line series?

Comment: Maybe you want to look at https://plot.ly/r/graphing-multiple-chart-types/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggested link in the comments does have some valuable resources, but they won't answer your questions directly. `iplot()` uses a pandas dataframe as input, and produces a stacked barplot. Here's an approach that will let you do exactly that, albeit without using `df.iplot()`

---

**First, the plot :**

[image]

**Now, the code**

My suggestion builds on an example found at: [plot.ly/pandas/bar-charts](https://plot.ly/pandas/bar-charts/). As you'll see that's an example that builds on a pandas dataframe - just like `df.iplot()`. You can simply take a series or 'trace' out of the stacked bars and display it as a line by changing

```
go.Bar(x=df['x'],
       y=df['y4'])
```

to:

```
 go.Scatter(x=df['x'],
            y=df['y4'])
```

I've also added a few elements to make it easier to display your results offline in a Jupyter notebook. Also note that I've changed the last line from `py.iplot(fig, filename='pandas-bar-chart-layout')` to just  `iplot(fig, filename='pandas-bar-chart-layout')`

**Complete snippet:**

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 20
x = np.linspace(1, 10, N)
y = np.random.randn(N)+3
y2 = np.random.randn(N)+6
y3 = np.random.randn(N)+9
y4 = np.random.randn(N)+12
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'y2':y2, 'y3':y3, 'y4':y4})
df.head()

data = [
    go.Bar(
        x=df['x'], # assign x as the dataframe column 'x'
        y=df['y']
    ),
    go.Bar(
        x=df['x'],
        y=df['y2']
    ),
    go.Bar(
        x=df['x'],
        y=df['y3']
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['x'],
        y=df['y4']
    )

]

layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    title='Stacked Bar with Pandas'
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# IPython notebook
iplot(fig, filename='pandas-bar-chart-layout')
```

Comment: One more question, I've got loads of bars. Is there a loop I can set up. Ie. for all columns in dataframe, create a go.Bar command?

Comment: @ fred.schwartz Glad to help! I'll take a loop at the `loop` when I find the time. Maybe later tonight or tomorrow. I don't see why it ***wouldn't*** work though. You could just loop on a list for your df columns and create a Bar object using `go.Bar` and store it in a list.

Comment: that makes sense. got it sorted. Just looped through and appended to list

Comment: thanks a lot, no one else seemed to have the answer to any of this

Comment: @fred.schwartz No problem! So your loop approach worked?

Answer (score 1):

answering to the last comment, I changed the code to include a loop like you asked.
Let me know if this helps:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 20
x = np.linspace(1, 10, N)
y = np.random.randn(N)+3
y2 = np.random.randn(N)+6
y3 = np.random.randn(N)+9
y4 = np.random.randn(N)+12
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'y2':y2, 'y3':y3, 'y4':y4})
df.head()

data = []
for i in df.columns:
    if i!= "x":
        data.append(
            go.Bar(
                x=df['x'], # assign x as the dataframe column 'x'
                y=df[i]
            )
        )

layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    title='Stacked Bar with Pandas'
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# IPython notebook
iplot(fig, filename='pandas-bar-chart-layout')
```